# how to pass relationship query parameter in spring data neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

returns error with below annoation.

```
@Query(value ="MATCH (n:Phone {phoneId:{0}})-[f:calling*0..{1}]-(m) OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r]-() return m,r")  
List<QueryPOJO> graph(String name,int level);
```

Description: Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}") (line 1, column 45 (offset: 44))

we need a elegant method to resolve this problem instead of write many interfaces.

```
   @Query(value ="MATCH (n:Phone {phoneId:{0}})-[f:calling*0..2]-(m) 
   OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r]-() return m,r")  
   List<QueryPOJO> grapht_2(String name,int level);

   @Query(value ="MATCH (n:Phone {phoneId:{0}})-[f:calling*0..3]-(m) 
   OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r]-() return m,r")  
   List<QueryPOJO> grapht_3(String name,int level);
```

cypher cannot resolve level relationship problem.

```
   MATCH (n:Person {name:'AAA'})-[f]-(m) where type(f)="Follow" OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r]-() return m,r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to resort to "manually" constructing the Cypher statement as a String and executing it through the Session, which allows execution of arbitrary Cypher queries via its query, queryForObject and queryForObjects methods.

Comment: how to override org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query methods in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

Cypher doesn't support limits on relationships like you did.You can try to limit the length of a path using function length() like this:

```
MATCH p=(n:Phone {phoneId:{0}})-[f:calling]-(m) OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r]-() where length(p)<{1} return m,r
```

Function length() gets the length of a path. Referring [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/),#Path Functions.